# How to check whether the telescope is properly collimated?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I have made a refractive type telescope. I have roughly checked that whether it is properly collimated, which is nothing but the conventional method. I looked through the telescope at a distant object and tried to focus there. But I want to be more accurate.

**Question:**  Is there any standard technique for infinity correction of such an optical instrument?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I HAVE NO ISSUE I IT?